# How to Merge CustomFont Class with Material design Libary

Tags: java, android

## My Custom Button that i'll use in my xml file:

i want to custom a button with shape of Rectangle(from Material Design library)
and adding a custom font to it.

this is what i come up with:

```
import com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle;

public class FontCustomButton extends Button {

 public FontCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    MyButton myButton = new MyButton(context,attrs);
    Typeface typeface =  myButton.getFont(context);
    this.setTypeface(typeface);
 }

  //inner class
  public class MyButton extends ButtonRectangle{
    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context, attrs);

  }

        //this Method will return my font as TypeFace
        public Typeface getFont(Context context){

            Typeface face=Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),"fonts/font_1.ttf");
            return face;
        }
  }

}
```

and here is how i want it to be called:

```
 <FontCustomButton 
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="@string/log_in"
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
         />
```

now my button should have the shape of Rectangle and the font at the same time.

link for the Material Design library that i use:

https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FontCustomButton extends ButtonRectangle {


 public FontCustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
     setCustomFont(context);
 }

 private void setCustomFont(Context context) {
    try {
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/font_1.ttf");            
        Field field = ButtonRectangle.class.getDeclaredField("textButton");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        TextView textView = (TextView) field.get(this);
        textView.setTypeface(face);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: The setTypeface will not work if you extend from ButtonRectangle as the java cannot resolve this method.

Comment: Oh ~ I'm sorry. 
I will change my answer : )

Comment: You can get access to textButton via method  getTextView(), there is no need for reflection

Comment: I used getTextView() , but that returns error..
I think, if you want getTextView() , then use super.getTextView(). ( i'm not try this way)

Comment: Thank you so much, Kim :D i just learned a new thing and i really appreciate it your time. <3